# Clear the content of a webview

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

How to clear the content of a webview?
I've tried with `weburl.url = 'about:blank'` but it seems not to work.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you care whether the DOM is actually gone? If not, just set an appropriate CSS style on the webview element to hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webview.src = 'about:blank'
```

should do what you want.